# do you have a good way of restricting the data returned by child collections in a rest api?

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Do you have a way of restricting the data returned by a REST API? For example, let's say I have a user search POST with an Expand parameter which accepts a string[] of child entities to include like "groups"

Let's say that groups has 10 attributes and I want to provide the ability to select only 2 of those group attributes like GroupId, GroupName as part of the request so the response only includes that data.

Do you have a good way of implementing this type of design?

Answer (score 1):

Create a good old DTO ([Data Transfer Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)) and map your database fields into the DTO and return the DTO.  It is a predetermined result (subset of fields).

-or-

I don't have access to my resource links at the moment, but there's a good course on Pluralsight for Web API 2 that discusses data-shaping.  It involves creating and returning an [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  This would be the technique to allow the calling program to pick and choose.  More flexibility, but more complexity.